# Custom event parameter is not passed correctly in test

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, testing, jestjs

I developed a JavaScript library to handle the events generated by a gamepad/joystick, and I also developed a series of tests with Jest for different test cases. But I have a problem with the tests: I can't figure out how to simulate the `gamepadconnected` and `gamepaddisconnected` events.

This is a simplified version of my code:

```
const gameControl = {
  // ...
  init: function() {
    window.addEventListener('gamepadconnected', e => {
      console.log('gamepad detected');
      if (!window.gamepads) window.gamepads = {};
      if (e.gamepad) {
        if (!window.gamepads[e.gamepad.index]) {
          window.gamepads[e.gamepad.index] = e.gamepad;
          // ...
        }
      }
    });
    window.addEventListener('gamepaddisconnected', e => {
      console.log('gamepad disconnected');
      if (e.gamepad) {
        delete window.gamepads[e.gamepad.index];
        // ...
      }
    });
  }
  // ...
};

gameControl.init();

export default gameControl;
```

`gamepadconnected` and `gamepaddisconnected` are native events triggered when a gamepad/joystick is connected or disconnected respectively. As a parameter, they receive an event object with the `gamepad` property that is an object with information about the connected/disconnected gamepad.

I tried dispatching the events manually in the tests, [creating my own custom event with the parameter I want](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CustomEvent/detail) (`gamepads` below is an array with gamepad's mock data). Something like this:

```
describe('gameControl', () => {

  // ...

  test('trigger gamepadconnected event', () => {
    const event = new CustomEvent('gamepadconnected', {
      detail: { gamepad: gamepads[0] }
    });
    global.dispatchEvent(event);
  });

  test('trigger gamepaddisconnected event', () => {
    const event = new CustomEvent('gamepaddisconnected', {
      detail: { gamepad: gamepads[0] }
    });
    global.dispatchEvent(event);
  });

  // ...

});
```

But, although the events are dispatched correctly and the event listener is triggered, the parameter doesn't make it through. For example, `gamepadconnected` is handled and I see in the console "gamepad detected," but the object `e` does not contain the property `gamepad` that I need.

I did a `console.log(e)` to see the properties of the event object, but my parameter is nowhere to be seen. This is all the `console.log` shows:

> CustomEvent { isTrusted: [Getter] }

What am I doing wrong? How can I achieve what I want and test the full code of the event handler for `gamepadconnected` and `gamepaddisconnected`?

As alternatives, I tried moving the `gamepad` property to the top level, or using `Event` instead of `CustomEvent`, but problem persists.

```
test('trigger gamepaddisconnected event', () => {
  const event = new CustomEvent('gamepaddisconnected', {
    gamepad: gamepads[0]
  });
  global.dispatchEvent(event);
});

test('trigger gamepaddisconnected event', () => {
  const event = new Event('gamepaddisconnected', {
    gamepad: gamepads[0]
  });
  global.dispatchEvent(event);
});
```

Comment: I'm also experiencing this.

I'm using the jest testing library. When I dispatch a CustomEvent from my src files w/event listeners in my test files, I can see the event details object. When I dispatch a CustomEvent from my test files w/event listeners in my src files, the detail object is not there and all I see when console.logging is:

    CustomEvent { isTrusted: [Getter] }

Answer (score 1):

a lazy hack that comes to mind: just check if e.detail.gamepad is defined  and then set e.gamepad to e.detail.gamepad

```
window.addEventListener('gamepadconnected', e => {
   if(e.detail && e.detail.gamepad) { e.gamepad = e.detail.gamepad }
...
```

Comment: This is a similar idea to what I ended up doing (`const egp = e.gamepad || e.detail.gamepad`). It works but, as you mention, it is a hack. I'm changing the library/app code to adapt it to the tests code, and that's not ideal.

Comment: true... but in the end you gain support for "emulated gamepads" though ;-)

Comment: yeah this is bad.... altering production code to suit a test!